# JQuery will NOT allow me to select specific radio button group

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, jquery-selectors

I was actually able to figure out my problem by assigning IDs to my individual radio buttons and manipulating them that way, but I'm still bothered that I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Here's the deal: let's say I have two groups of radio buttons that look something like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="Group1True" value="True" /> True
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="Group1False" value="False" /> False

<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" id="Group2True" value="True" /> True
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" id="Group2False" value="False" /> False
```

I want the **RadioGroup2** buttons affected, depending on what is selected in **RadioGroup1**.  For example, if **ID="Group1True"** is selected, then I want the **RadioGroup2** buttons to be hidden (I have the **RadioGroup2** buttons wrapped within a <div> tag to do this).

If, however, **ID="Group1False"** is selected, not only do I want the **RadioGroup2** buttons to reappear (which works fine), I also want the **RadioGroup2** buttons to be *reset* and *unchecked*.  **This** is where I run into problems.

I've tried all of the following combinations (and even a few more that I can't remember).  *None* of them do what I want.

```
if ( $("#RadioGroup1:checked").val() == "False" )
{

// HERE'S where I run into problems:

    // This line not only unchecks the RadioGroup2 buttons, it also unchecks
    // the RadioGroup1 buttons, which I DO NOT want it to do!!!!!!!!!

    $("input:radio[@name=RadioGroup2]").removeAttr("checked");


    // This line gives me a JavaScript error saying:
    // "Object doesn't support this property or method"!!!!!!!

    $("input[@name=RadioGroup2]").removeAttr("checked");


    // This line does absolutely nothing

    $("RadioGroup2").removeAttr("checked");

}
```

As I said, I was able to resolve my issue by referencing IDs instead of radio group names, but I'm still frustrated that I don't know why this doesn't work.

Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: why are you using "@"? just use :radio[name=RadioGroup2] as the selector http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: CSS selector syntax is not the same as xpath.

Comment: @ianpgall -- Do me a favor -- please write this as an answer so I can mark it as the answer!!!

Comment: nahh don't worry about it, someone else answered with the same thing but more info too, i'm not worried about being the correct answer, just glad you got it. i'll add the link to the accepted answer's explanation though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector syntax is incorrect.

```
$('input[name="RadioGroup1"]').whatever();
```

(Actually I guess it's not "incorrect" so much as "wrong"; your selectors were looking for a value on the "@name" attribute instead of "name".)

The `#` is for "id" values, not "name", so `#RadioGroup1` won't work for you.

Instead of `.removeAttr("checked")` you can alternatively set the "checked" property to `false`:

```
$('input[name="RadioGroup1"]').prop("checked", false);
```

You could also give groups of radio buttons a "class" value, which is a little more concise than using the element name:

```
$('input.radio-group-1')
```

or whatever.  Of course, it'd mean more markup.

Personally I think that's the better way to go; when you're messing with the DOM, you should manipulate DOM object **properties**, not element attributes.  Removing the attribute would probably work however.

Comment: +1 However, the `@` in the attibute selector seems to be from an older jQuery version, where `.prop` was not yet available.

Comment: @pimvdb I've been using jQuery for a really long time, and I've never had to use "@" - I think that's an XSL/xpath thing, but it's not CSS syntax.

Comment: I *know* # is for IDs; that was a typo on my part. Removing the @ was the answer I was looking for; the reference I was using used it, which is why I had it in there.

Comment: @RayK. Yes that's why my code involving the "name" attribute does not have the "@" sign in it. What reference would have that in it?  Seems kind-of amazing as it's *never* been correct CSS selector syntax.

Comment: @pointy : [Here's where I found it](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-quick-guide.htm)

Comment: @RayK. wow. Well I can understand how you'd be led astray by that; it looks so professional and authoritative :-)

Comment: @pointy : I just sent the site admins an email to fix the error so no one else has to go through the several hours of frustration that I just went through!!!